# How would I create a custom binding from a computed property?

Tags: swiftui

So I know that I can create a custom binding in the view itself (in the `body`) But I'm wondering if I can just have a computed property return me a Binding .

I am using generics to handle whatever type I pass in. And then show that *generic type* in a `Text` and of course to do that it needs to be a string.

So here is what I am trying to do.

```
struct EditStatView<Stat>: View {

@Binding var statValue: Stat

let statLabel: String

    var stringText: Binding<String> {
        let stringValue = String(describing: statValue)
        return Binding<String>(stringValue) //<- Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String?>'
     }
}
```

Confused about how to continue

Comment: Get `get` part of the binding would be easy, but you'd need some way to convert from `String` into `Stat` -- without that, the `set` part of the Binding won't work.

Comment: @jnpdx so this is not doable?

Comment: Not unless either you have a reliable method for the conversion (unlikely unless you constrain Stat somehow) or you don't actually care about the `set` part of the Binding (unlikely as well).

Comment: @SergioBost: if you do not want update View with computed property, you can use and Bind it for background work, but if you are trying update or render View it would not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
struct EditStatParentView: View {
    @State var sample1: String = "init"
    @State var sample2: Int = 0
    @State var sample3: Double = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(sample1)
            EditStatView(statValue: $sample1, statLabel: "string")
            Divider()
            Text(sample2.description)
            EditStatView(statValue: $sample2, statLabel: "int")
            Divider()
            Text(sample3.description)
            EditStatView(statValue: $sample3, statLabel: "double")
        }
    }
}
struct EditStatView<Stat>: View where Stat: Any{
    
    @Binding var statValue: Stat
    let statLabel: String
    //The point of a Binding is a two-way connection
    //It needs a parent that is a source of truth such as
    //@State, @Published, ManagedObject
    var statProxy: Binding<String>{
        Binding(get: {
            return String(describing: statValue)
        }, set: {
            // because of the two-way connection you need to make sure $0 matches the type of the original Stat or it will fail.
            //Here is a very crude way to make it adapt
            statValue = $0 as? Stat ?? Double($0) as? Stat ?? Int($0) as? Stat ?? statValue //If all else fails just return the original
        })
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(String(describing: statValue))
            TextField(statLabel, text: statProxy)
        }
    }
}

struct EditStatView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditStatParentView()
    }
}
```